# Bootstrap nav menu does not scroll/affix after jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, affix

I am using jQuery to empty a div, then load a php page into the emptied div:

```
$("#main-container").empty();
$("#main-container").load("blog.php");
```

Everything works except for the Bootstrap side scrolling nav menu (included in blog.php) which affixes and scrolls as intended when merged into a single static HTML page, but not when separated and loaded in using JS as described.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="navmenu-side" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <li><a href="#section1">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Category 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navmenu-side.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
#navmenu-side.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I assume this could be a result of Bootstrap events being triggered by the original page/DOM load but then not being triggered after jQuery loading. How can I make the Bootstrap side nav menu scroll/affix after it is loaded into a page using jQuery's load method?

Comment: Can you create us a jsfiddle, or a bootply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this

```
$("#main-container").load("blog.php", function () {
  $('#myAffix').affix('checkPosition');
});
```

Comment: This makes the menu scroll again, though it doesn't respect the 'data-offset-top' until I scroll to the top of the page, meaning it jumps and overlays the content residing above. How can I remind it of this restriction? Cheers.